# How do I add an Image in Xamarin while using Jetbrain Rider?

Tags: c#, xamarin, jetbrains-ide, rider

I'm currently using Jetbrain's Rider as an IDE and there aren't any tutorials online about managing image resources with Xamarin and Rider together. Right now I can't get an image to display at all. My Project tree goes

- Testing

  - Model
  - Resources

    - drawable

      - ball.png
  - View

    - MainPage.xaml

      - MainPage.xaml.cs

In my .cs file I have this code. _s is a StackLayout and I know that adding to it's children works.

```
var image = new Image { Source = ImageSource.FromResource("Testing.Resources.drawable.ball.png", typeof(MainPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly) };
_s.Children.Add(image);
```

I have ball.png's build action set as Embedded Resource. This is all I could find online in documentation stuff. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to change 'drawable' into 'Drawable'?

Comment: The folder is lowercase, I forgot to change that in the question

Comment: i'm using this Video for embedded resource image for Xamarin.Forms:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVpbklb6vDc&ab_channel=XamarinDevelopers

It's work well for me

Comment: Unfortunately I need the Image to be created in my C# class dynamically instead of through xaml. Great resource though thank you!

Comment: That's no differences between visual studio and rider to display an image through C#, I tried locally and it works well. Could you test it in the visual studio?

Comment: It works in Visual Studio.  Rider's embedded resource naming convention must be different then?

Answer (score 0):

I tested it out in Visual Studio per @Steven's request, and it worked. I didn't change any code, switched back to Rider, and it magically worked. I guess that's what I get for not using Visual Studio.